# Objective-C Game Programming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, lua, game-center

i'm starting game programming (for iPhone) and i'm would love to know more about it.
From what i seen i can choose 3 different ways:

```
1) Lua on Kobold 2D
2) Cocos 2d
3) Basic UIKit
```

Which ones are the real differences? For the ones that already have tried them, why should i pick one technique instead of another?

Do you know witch style was picked same the most game like: Angry Birds, Fruit Ninja, Ruzzle, Draw Something, Candy Crush, Words whit friends, Temple Run, Four pic one word, Song Pop, Fun run, and so on.

Are there any other ways to programming game to iPhone? Such as other Kit or API that i didn't mention?

Thank's

Comment: ...and iOS 7 has new frameworks for games, if you are an apple developer you can take a look at the apple downloadable sample (doc and project: Explained Adventure

Comment: Which are the differences why one is better than another?

Comment: I strongly suggest looking into Sprite Kit, available to developers and publicly available on Sept 10 th with iOS 7. You can't write an entire app in Kobold2D Lua but you can do so with Corona.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cocos2D is a proper 2D game engine. You can find so many tutorial sources on the net. you can also use cocos2D with box2d or chipmunk physics engine if you need physics simulations or accurate collisions in game world. Beware though there are 2 versions of cocos2D one that uses openglES 1.0 ; which is used for  older ios devices and the one that uses openGL ES 2.0;  which has a support for shaders. Also there is a flavour of Cocos2D called Cocos2D-x which is written with c++. so if you planning for cross plaltform go for Cocos2D-x. be warned though cocos2D-x doesn't have as much tutorial as the Cocos2D.

Kobold 2d is actually suppose to be extended and improved version of cocos2d  that acts as a wrapper arouund cocos2D, so that creating games are a bit more simpler compare to creating in cocos2D. However this is more likely based on personal view of the author of the Kobold2D. Personally I haven't tried it but I believe its going to cause more headache to me then it would help or more likely it will limit me down since I already started grasping the idea of developing games. Also there is less amount of tutorials on the web for Kobold2.

Basic UIKIT. erm... this is the hardest choice you can make. UIKIT is composed of OPENGL ES  and QuartzCore framework and uses these to draw the your game on the scene. So its not a game engine.  if you are going for UIKIT you will be reinventing lots of things from scratch. rendering textures, managing your scenes, handling your sprites, and resources.

Obviously rendering is not the only thing  the game does. if you going for UIKIT you also have to find solutions for collisions "*such as when a paddle hits a ball*" and user interactions "*such as how player controlls the game with touch screen*".  So my suggestion is keep away from UIKIT and start with Cocos2D. it will make the life simple enough to get you going yet complex enough to let you have freedom and think.

Comment: Which would you suggest for a simple game like Ruzzle or Fruit Ninja? Lua, Cocos, Kobold?

Comment: first lua is not an engine. its a scripting language used by an engine. the game Ruzzle and Fruit Ninja have completely different game play. Ruzzle is a word game. so there is nothing seems too complex going on in your scene. Kobold2D would enough to pull this off.For fruit ninja, it has elements of physical simulation such as gravity that pulls fruits down. it has fruits that collides with eachother, slashed in to pieces. it has different game modes with different game play & particle effects.My suggestion is cocos2D because there are many tutorials out there teaches how to do these stuffs.

Comment: since I can not add comments to other peoples answer(stab code), Ill write it here. Cocos2D is a game engine doesn't support ARC out of the box, however you can still activate the ARC for cocos2D. In addition to that Cocos2D also written in Objective C just like Kobold2D. If I am a beginner, and if I want to learn how to start making games I would definitely go for something that is simple yet should have a community that is large enough to help me out.  in stack-exchange alone, 128 question asked under kobold2d and over 5000 questions asked under cocos2D.

Comment: if Kobold is an extension of Cocos, wouldn't it be good for both games? What about Lua? When be useful to use?

Comment: it is more likely to be good for both games however, will you be able to find enough tutorials if you hit a wall on your development process. thats one think that you need to take into consideration. the developer of Kobold2D has book titled Learn Cocos2D game Development. this  was also the first book that I red when I started cocos2d. The final chapter of this book contained Kobol2D. the rest is all about Cocos2D itself. http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/blog/.

Comment: As for Lua, dont mistaken that the game is coded in Lua. Lua is used as a scripting language. in games its purpose is to reduce development time.  A most commonly used place would be in Game A.I where you need to modify A.I values over and over again till you got it right. you could still do this without a scripting language but development would need longer time since the code needs to be re-compiled rather then being interpreted. Why are you so keen on Lua?

Comment: i heard talking about Lua and i know it's used for many games, which do you think that are pro and cons of both Lua and Cocos? Is there any other game system you recommend?

Comment: I dont understand why you are comparing lua to cocos2D or other engines. cocos2D is a game engine lua is a language. they are not same thing. if you can not understand the difference between game engine and a scripting language then I really doubt that you are ready for game development. http://www.lua.org is the official side for lua. all the info you need is there and how it used in game is also there.

Comment: i know that Cocos is an engine and Lua is a language, when i compare i mean to ask if is the best to create a game using Cocos(with objective-C) or other SDK like Corona (with Lua). Which are the pro and cons? What do you recommend?

Comment: I can not commend on corona never used it before so my knowledge on that equal to 0. however I heard many great things about it except the cost. this is the main reason I also choose cocos2D. there used to be another engine called Torque2D. I am not sure but i think its not updated anymore. anyway we need to stop this long chat or we both going to get hunted.

Answer (score 4):

- lua is a different programming language than objective-c, but you can use it in objective-c with the Wax api.
- Kobold2d is an extended version of cocos2d, but i haven't tried so can't say much.
- cocos it's like a wrapper that help you drawing lines, using collisions etc.
- unity it's most used with 3d games
- open gl it's more raw and you have to customize everything, it's more powerful but it require way more work

all of them are pretty much just wrapper frameworks that help you writing games because they include different functions that you normally would write on ur own. unity it's usually chosed for 3d games, open gl for bigger project but will require way more work. if you want to do a simple 2d games the real choice is between lua( throught wax api ), kobold and cocos.

personally i prefer kobold, because it's still objective-c ( lua uses it only with wax ) but still has many helpful functions and uses arc ( which cocos doesn't ) but try to see if other programmers give you different advices.

i don't know which is best to chose but i know that Angry birds is done with Lua ( which is a cross-platform programming language )

read more on this link
http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/08/comparison-lua-scripting-corona-sdk-wax-kobold2d/

http://www.kobold2d.com/display/KKSITE/_Kobold2D+vs+Cocos2D+Comparison+Chart

Comment: Why should use Lua instead of Cocos?

Comment: i never used lua but i heard it's very easy to use, with corona sdk you can create a lua game even without being a programmer. cocos2d is objective-c.
Lua is not OOP, Cocos is OOP that's the main difference. then it's all about details.
lua makes it easier to use images, sounds, physics. but more simplicity means less control.

aside from this difference you should consider few things when deciding what system to approach for your game:

1) do you want a free system? many sdk like corona, or unity require you to pay to use them, unity require 199$ for ios and 199$ for droid. Cocos is free

Comment: **2)** u want to use a simple sdk or u want to be able to mix libraries?cocos let u decide to use any library that you want, lua is a closed system, because it's not objective-c but a total different language.



**3)** a company like the one doing kobold could close, how would u update your game?


**4)** community. it's important to chose something that let u have support from a big community. cocos n lua have surely a bigger community than unity. OpenGl has a big community too.

Comment: **5)** the style of the game you need to do. a word game, a platform n so on. every language has a better support for one or another style

i heard very good about MOAI sdk, many companies are using it. it's open source, powerful. it uses lua.

So to summarize, you need to consider many things,
but personally to start, in your case, i'd go for cocos :)